# how to assign value of data box from database in php

Tags: php, oracle

Good morning to Everyone,

I have a Question regarding  assigning the value date box from a database entry. I'm retrieving value from database DATE entry, assign it to a variable and that pass that variable to date box. bit i doesn't work.

first I retread the value from the database:

```
<?php 
     $conn = oci_connect('login', 'password', 'localhost/XE');
     $myStr = "SELECT input_date FROM REc_INFO where idcode = 'RS0021'";
     $stdi = oci_parse($conn, $myStr);
     oci_execute($stdi);
     $row = oci_fetch_array($stdi, OCI_BOTH);
     $tempDate = $row[0];
     $newDate = date("m/d/Y", strtotime($tempDate));
     echo $newDate;
  ?>
```

I try to output `$newDate` to make sure its not empty and it returns the value of `03/27/2013`. But when I try to pass `$NewDate` to the date box it doesn't work

```
 <input type="date" name="sdate" id="sdate" value="<?php echo $newDate; ?>" required>
```

I wonder what am I doing wrong. Would be gratefull if someone can point it out to me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: date inputs require date values to be in RFC 3339-compliant format, which your `m/d/Y` format is not.

Comment: follow the rules and use a supported date format.

Comment: shall I pass `$tempDate` straight to the value of date box?

Comment: that depends on if it's an RFC3339 date or not, doesn't it?

Comment: originally in the database its `27-MAR-2013`

Comment: is it RFC33339 format?